# I have no clue what's going on

Tags: python, django, module, python-module

I just got to finishing a tutorial with the following link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOVLhM6_6t0&t=572s

and the last step is to check that the server is running properly using `python manage.py runserver`

however when I try to do this, the usual error pops up:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

which I was able to solve with the absoulte path solutions provided online.

However my problem is not that

the problem comes when I finally reach the right `cd` to be in and all of this errors appear in the terminal:

```
python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute 
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 81, in handle  
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module 
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myProject1\main\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myProject1\main\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 425, in run_from_argv        
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [
           ^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings        
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\juand\OneDrive\Documentos\Python programs\Project1\myVenv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module 
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

> Blockquote

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject1'
```

I have no clue what even is going on here or how could I solve it. I've been stuck here for the past hour. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should add your error as code snippet in this post instead of google docs. Also can you show your project structure and what folder you are running `manage.py runserver` from?

Comment: Yeah sure I'd love to let you see the folder, however idk how lol, im sorry im really bad at this. btw I did add the code snippet instead of the google doc as you suggested it

Comment: You could take the screenshot of the folder structure and then add it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a git page with the code you setup? This sounds like a configuration problem.

Answer (score -1):

The end line says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject1'", so I think you need to have myProject1.py in the same folder as the script which you are running, or specify the path to myProject1.py in python path.

Comment: First, where do you get access to a myProject1.py in the file explorer, I can only see it as a folder full of files, and second, how could I specify the ladder?